# Powershell script extracting .zip files issues

Tags: powershell

Hi Guys I followed this guide:

http://www.howtogeek.com/tips/how-to-extract-zip-files-using-powershell/

But I keep getting a null value error.

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:11 char:1
+ $shell.Namespace($destination).copyhere($item)

Im not sure why as my destination variable is set?Below is my code

```
function Expand-ZIPFile($file, $destination)
{
echo $file
echo $destination
$shell = new-object -com shell.application
$zip = $shell.NameSpace($file)
echo $zip.Items()
foreach($item in $zip.items())
{
echo $item
$shell.Namespace($destination).copyhere($item)
}
}

Expand-ZIPFile “D:\temp\12102015.zip” “D:\temp\howtogeek”
```

and my output:

```
D:\temp\12102015.zip
D:\temp\howtogeek

                               Count Application                          Parent                               Verbs                               
                               ----- -----------                          ------                               -----                               
                                   2 System.__ComObject                                                        System.__ComObject                  
                                     System.__ComObject                   System.__ComObject                                                       
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:11 char:1
+ $shell.Namespace($destination).copyhere($item)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

                                     System.__ComObject                   System.__ComObject                                                       
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:11 char:1
+ $shell.Namespace($destination).copyhere($item)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

Answer:

My destination directory did not exist :S

Comment: I see smart quotes that were copied from the site. Does it work when you change those to regular quotes? `Expand-ZIPFile "D:\temp\12102015.zip" "D:\temp\howtogeek"`. " vs “

Comment: Does `$destination` directory exists?

Comment: Ah good @PetSerAl you are here. The smart quote thing should not be a show stopper under a certain circumstance IIRC. I remember reading something from you in an earlier post but I can remember.....

Comment: Hi Guys thanks for the response. PetSerAI is bang on the money with the directory not existing, my mistake :S